# Is it possible to use two different Owin startup file at run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, mef

I am using an Asp.net MVC 5 app with [MEF framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) to allow me to design MVC app as a plugin to in the main app.

I have a need where one of my plugin needs to have its own `OwinStart` up class that runs after the the master Owin class which belongs to my main app.

In other words `main.dll` has `Startup` class which always needs to run first, then `plugin.dll` has a `Startup` class that needs to run second.

Is it possible to have 2 Own Startup classes?

From the [Docs about detecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) the StartUp class

> The `OwinStartup` attribute overrides the naming convention. You can
>   also specify a friendly name with this attribute, however, using a
>   friendly name requires you to also use the `appSetting` element in the
>   configuration file.

So I tried adding a friendly name like so

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("pluginStartup", typeof(plugin.Startup))]
```

The added the following in the config file

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Main.Startup, Main" />
</appSettings>
```

But that does not file my `Plugin.Startup` it only runs `Main.Startup`.

Is there a way to run two different `Startup` classes?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not seems possible to run multiple startup files.

However, I used reflection to get the job done. Basically, I search all assemblies for any class the implements a `IAppConfiguration` interface, then call the `Configuration` on that instance.

Here is how I did it.

I created an interface

```
public interface IAppConfiguration
{
    void Configuration(IAppBuilder app);
}
```

Then in my `main.dll` I added the following code to my `Startup` class.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigurePlugins(app);
    }

    private static void ConfigurePlugins(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                var startups = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass && typeof(IAppConfiguration ).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList();

                foreach (Type startup in startups)
                {
                    var config = (IAppConfiguration )Activator.CreateInstance(startup);

                    config.Configuration(app);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```